# Unable to configure second level cache in hibernate 4.x

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache

I am using `hibernate 4.3` and `MySQL 5.0.`I am trying to configure a second level cache in my example as follows.

My `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

My Entity class

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Cacheable
public class Employee { ...}
```

I am getting following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jndi/JndiNameException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2252)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.<clinit>(AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.java:77)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:125)
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:46)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:83)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:295)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2442)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2438)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1855)
at com.example.hibernate.Hibernate4Main.main(Hibernate4Main.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiNameException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 22 more
```

What is missing in my configuration? I know second level cache configuration in `hibernate 4.x` is different for `3.x`. I have searched that but not getting working answer for me.

*Thanks for help.*

Answer (score 0):

Propbable reasons why you are getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`
1) Class is not available in Java Classpath.
2) You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.
3) Any start-up script is overriding Classpath environment variable.

4) Because NoClassDefFoundError is a sub class of java.lang.LinkageError it can also come if one of it dependency like native library may not available.

4) Check for java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in your log file. NoClassDefFoundError due to failure of static initialization is quite common.

5) If you are working in J2EE environment than visibility of Class among multiple Classloaders can also cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: It should not throw this exception because i have all required jars and i am using eclipse IDE.Do you know any url where i can get example of second level cache for hibernate 4.x.